# Matlab Date Vector

Tags: matlab, date, vector

I have an array A with time information in the format hhmmss. Ultimately, I would like to normalize this array by indicating the elapsed time (in seconds, starting from the first time).

> A = [  150213
>         150013
>         145813
>         145613
>         145413
>         145313
>         145213
>         145113
>         145013
>         144943
>         144913
>         144843
>         144833
>         144823
>         144813
>         144803
>         144753
>         144743
>         144741
>         144739
>         144737
>         144735
>         144733
>         144731
>         144729
>         144727
>         144725
>         144723
>         144721
>         144719]

So, in the end the array should be :

> A_updated = [894
>   774
>   654
>   534
>   414
>   354
>   294
>   234
>   174
>   144
>   114
>   84
>   74
>   64
>   54
>   44
>   34
>   24
>   22
>   20
>   18
>   16
>   14
>   12
>   10
>   8
>   6
>   4
>   2
>   0
>   ]

What would be the quickest 'Matlab way' to proceed with this? Many thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: What is the type of the elements in the A array?

Comment: each element is of the "single" type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Matlab in a while, so forgive the syntax mistakes, and I don't have it available right now, but here's what I would try. Basically, convert everything to seconds then subtract the last element.

```
At = uint32(A);
A_updated = mod(At,100);
At = floor(At ./ 100);
A_updated = A_updated + mod(At,100) * 60;
At = floor(At ./ 100);
A_updated = A_updated + At * 3600;
A_updated = A_updated - A_updated(end);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick assistance ! I implemented your suggestion in Matlab the result was : 
A_updated =
1.0e+04 *
    5.1367
    5.1175
    5.3143
    5.2951
    5.2759
    5.2663
    5.2567
    5.2471
    5.2375
    5.2338
    5.2279
    5.2242
    5.2222
    5.2203
    5.2183
    5.2163
    5.2165
    5.2146
    5.2142
    5.2138
    5.2134
    5.2130
    5.2126
    5.2122
    5.2118
    5.2115
    5.2111
    5.2107
    5.2103
    5.2099

I will go through your method and I hope to find what went wrong.

Comment: The result was... what? :)

Comment: sorry...i press the ENTER button too quickly

Comment: I see, that's probably because the numbers are single, not integer. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @elnigno I've corrected your "[end]" sintax and also the subtraction needed to be made after the "*3600". PLEASE CHECK IF YOU AGREE

Comment: @LuisMendo, thanks for the "(end)" but Justinnl required the final result to be in A_updated, so I've reverted that.

Comment: @elnigno But then you need to do it in two lines: first `A_updated = A_updated + mod(At,100) * 3600`, and then `A_updated = A_updated - A_updated(end)`. Otherwise the value you subtract is not correct (it doesn't include the hours). That was my point

Comment: There is still an error with the final answer. Now the A_updated reads: 

A_updated =
       51294
       51174
       54654
       54534
       54414
       54354
       54294
       54234
       54174
       50544
       50514
       50484
       50474
       50464
       50454
       50444
       50494
       50424
       50422
       50420
       50418
       50416
       50414
       50412
       50410
       50408
       50406
       50404
       50402
       50400

Comment: Now I see @LuisMendo, does it have to do with precedence (I don't have Matlab to verify myself)? If so, splitting in two as you said should fix it.

Comment: After a closer inspection, I noticed that elements 3 until 9 are wrong. I think that this has to do with a round off mistake upon application of the "mod" statement

A_updated =
         894
         774
        4254
        4134
        4014
        3954
        3894
        3834
        3774
         144
         114
          84
          74
          64
          54
          44
          94
          24
          22
          20
          18
          16
          14
          12
          10
           8
           6
           4
           2
           0

Comment: Hmm, yes, it looks like those elements are 3600 too high. I guess it's because the './' is actually performing a float division, which causes numbers higher than 50 round up to 1 when divided by 100.
I realized that the last `mod` is not necessary.
I'm updating the answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in Octave so you may need to adjust the syntax for `datenum`:

```
B = double(A);
hh = floor(B/10000);
mm = floor((B-hh*10000)/100);
ss = B - hh*10000 - mm*100;
C = datenum(2013,10,28,hh,mm,ss);
elapsed_time = (C-C(end))*3600*24;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. A minor problem with the datenum function here is the fact that only double arrays can be used.Is there an alternative and/or are there suggested adaptions for this issue?

Comment: Thank you for the addition. The numbers now do match, however in reversed order ( i.e. [0 2 4 ... 894]  instead of [  894 774 654 .... 0].  

elapsed_time =
  Columns 1 through 12
         0    2.0000    4.0000    6.0000    8.0000   10.0000   12.0000   14.0000   16.0000   18.0000   20.0000   22.0000
  Columns 13 through 24
   24.0000   34.0000   44.0000   54.0000   64.0000   74.0000   84.0000  114.0000  144.0000  174.0000  234.0000  294.0000
  Columns 25 through 30
  354.0000  414.0000  534.0000  654.0000  774.0000  894.0000

Comment: OK, I (wrongly) assumed you wanted them in ascending order. I'll make one more update to the answer.